# Passing code as an argument (C++)

Tags: c++

How would I go about passing a code block to a function in C++. In C# I can do something like this:

```
void Example(Action action)
{
    action();
}

Example(() => {
    //do something
});
```

All help and tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: google `std::function` and `c++ lambda`

Comment: Function pointers are very handy...

Comment: Function objects are useful too.  Search the internet for `operator()`.

Comment: Take a look at [The Astonishing Functionoid!](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functionoids)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example to get started with...

```
void Example(void (*x)(void))
{
    x();
}
```

and the call would be...

```
Example([] { cout << "do something\n"; });
```

This is very similar to your C# example.  And there are better, more versatile ways of doing this as the comments suggest.  If you had wanted to return a value and take a parameter you could do something like this...

```
int Example2(int (*y)(int i), int p)
{
    return y(p);
}
// ...
auto ret = Example2([](int p) -> int { cout << p << "\n"; return p; }, 2);
```

This would be similar to the C# version as follows

```
int Example2(Func<int,int> y, int p)
{
    return y(p);
}
// ...
var ret = Example2((p) => { /*etc*/ return p; }, 2);
```

Comment: Accepting a function pointer is extremely limiting, it means you can just pass only non-capturing lambdas or plain function pointers (=> no bound method calls, just to make an example). You should accept an `std::function` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`std::function<Result(Param1, Param2, ...)>` is a decent default, but you have a few options:

1. Declare an auxiliary function and pass a pointer to it. This was the only way to go about things in C, and a conventional way to do it in C++98.

   ```
   void example(void (*action)()) {
       action();
   }

   void example_action() {
       std::cout << "action\n";
   }

   example(example_action);
   ```
2. Accept a function pointer, and pass a lambda that captures no variables. Lambdas are available in C++11 and later.

   ```
   void example(void (*action)()) {
       action();
   }

   example([]() {
       std::cout << "action\n";
   });
   ```
3. Accept a callable template type parameter (one with `operator()` defined), and pass a lambda that may capture variables, or any other callable object (“functor”).

   ```
   template<class F>
   void example(F action) {
       action();
   }

   int x = 4;
   example([x]() {
       std::cout << "action (" << x << ")\n";
   });

   struct example_action {
       void operator()() {
           std::cout << "action\n";
       }
   };

   example(example_action());
   ```
4. Accept a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object, and pass a lambda that may capture variables.

   ```
   void example(std::function<void()> action) {
       action();
   }

   int x = 4;
   example([x]() {
       std::cout << "action (" << x << ")\n";
   });
   ```
5. Declare an auxiliary function and take pointer to it at compile time.

   ```
   template<void (*action)()>
   void example() {
       action();
   }

   example<example_action>();
   ```

Like any template, #3 will generate a specialisation of `example` for every action type with which you call it, so it may increase your binary size, but it has no runtime overhead. #4 will allocate space for the closure at runtime, but will only generate one definition of `example` in the binary. #5 is rarer, but it allows the passed-in function to benefit from optimisations such as inlining.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 equivalent would be:

```
void Example(const std::function<void()>& action)
{
    // always good to make sure that action has a valid target
    if(action != nullptr)
        action();
}

Example([] {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::function<void()>` instead of `Action` and the C++ syntax for lambda functions:

```
void Example(std::function<void()> action)
{
    action();
}

Example([]() {
    //do something
});
```

`std::function`, in comparison to @Les's solution with function pointers, allows you to pass lambdas which capture context and in general any other kind of callable objects.